How to rotate Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual without clipping?
In my .NET 4.8 WPF application I have a window with two ContainerVisual elements:

_rootContainerVisual
_containerVisualToRotate

Is a child of _rootContainerVisual

Displays multiple images on multiple sprites that are positioned next to each other in a certain way in the real application.

Displays a fill brush in the provided example code.

The content is bigger than the size of both ContainerVisual




I would like to rotate the complete _containerVisualToRotate around the z-axis.
When I do this I notice that part of the images/brush inside the  _containerVisualToRotate is clipped, although there is enough space.
In standard WPF I used a negative margin to make it work.
Example xaml (no code behind required):
<Window x:Class="PlayingAroundInWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayingAroundInWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" MouseEnter="Window_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Window_MouseLeave">
    <Grid Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-100">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="15"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Opacity="0.2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="72">Test with standard WPF</Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

This leads to the following: the inner content is bigger then the visible part of the view -> the inner content is not getting clipped during rotation.

I tried to do something similar with the _containerVisualToRotate by

using the Clip property with negative numbers.

setting the Size property of the _containerVisualToRotate to a high number

settting the RelativeSizeAdjustment to values >5.0f

setting the Size property of the rectangle to a high number


However, none of this leads to the desired result.
Here is my example code behind (the xaml is actually an empty window):
public partial class ContainerVisualExample : Window
{
    private IntPtr _hwndHost;
    private Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor _compositor;
    private Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionTarget _target;
    private Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual _rootContainerVisual;
    private Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual _containerVisualToRotate;

    public ContainerVisualExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += ContainerVisualExample_Loaded;
    }

    private void ContainerVisualExample_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupCompositions();
        AddRectangleToContainer();
        RotateContainerVisual();
    }

    private void SetupCompositions()
    {
        _hwndHost = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

        _compositor = new Compositor();
        _target = _compositor.CreateDesktopWindowTarget(_hwndHost, false);

        // Setup the _rootContainerVisual.
        _rootContainerVisual = _compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
        _rootContainerVisual.RelativeSizeAdjustment = Vector2.One;
        _rootContainerVisual.Offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        _containerVisualToRotate = _compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
        _containerVisualToRotate.RelativeSizeAdjustment = new Vector2(5.0f, 5.5f);
        _containerVisualToRotate.Offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        _containerVisualToRotate.Size = new Vector2(10000, 10000);
        _containerVisualToRotate.Clip = _compositor.CreateInsetClip(-10000, -10000, -10000, -10000);        
        _containerVisualToRotate.CenterPoint = new Vector3(400, 225, 0);
        _rootContainerVisual.Children.InsertAtTop(_containerVisualToRotate);
        _target.Root = _rootContainerVisual;
    }
    private void AddRectangleToContainer()
    {
        // Create a rectangle element
        Windows.UI.Composition.SpriteVisual rectangleVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        rectangleVisual.Size = new Vector2(10000, 10000);

        // Set the fill color of the rectangle to light blue
        Windows.UI.Color lightBlueColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 173, 216, 230);
        Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionColorBrush fillBrush = _compositor.CreateColorBrush(lightBlueColor);
        rectangleVisual.Brush = fillBrush;

        // Add the rectangle to the _containerVisualToRotate
        _containerVisualToRotate.Children.InsertAtTop(rectangleVisual);
    }
    private void RotateContainerVisual()
    {
        _containerVisualToRotate.RotationAngleInDegrees = 45.0f;
    }
}

However, this still leads to clipping:

Now, I'm out of ideas on how to get this working.
As I wrote above: rotating the inner content (in the example the rectangle) is not really an option, since it contains several sprites that would all need to be rotated individually around the same center point.
Is there any other way?

Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual is not a WPF System.Windows.Media.ContainerVisual as mentioned in the question title. Please clarify what exactly you are doing here.

Does this answer your question? XAML Image Fit to Parent After Rotation

@Clemens, thank you for your comment. It looks like the title is misleading.
However, the application is indeed using Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual.
The reason is that the brushes for the images are based on DirectX.

@Orace,  unfortunately no. But thanks for pointing that out.

I cannot add comment,
have you tried LayoutTransform
<Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="15"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
</Grid.LayoutTransform>


Thanks for the answer. That would mean that the ContainerVisual are children of the Grid. However, to the best of my knowledge that is not possible, because Grid.Children are System.Windows.UIElements. And the ContainerVisual does not implement that interface.

Thanks for your kind reply, I'm not expert with visual operations, however, I'm using simple rotate for textbox or other controls using layoutTransform instead of RenderTransform

    public partial class ContainerVisualExample : Window
    {
        private Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor _compositor;
        private Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual _rootContainerVisual;
        private Windows.UI.Composition.ContainerVisual _containerVisualToRotate;

        public ContainerVisualExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += ContainerVisualExample_Loaded;
        }

        private void ContainerVisualExample_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetupCompositions();
            AddRectangleToContainer();
            RotateContainerVisual();
            AdjustRootContainerSize();
        }

        private void SetupCompositions()
        {
            // Create a Compositor instance
            _compositor = new Compositor();

            // Create the root ContainerVisual
            _rootContainerVisual = _compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
            _rootContainerVisual.RelativeSizeAdjustment = Vector2.One;

            // Create the ContainerVisual to rotate
            _containerVisualToRotate = _compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
            _containerVisualToRotate.RelativeSizeAdjustment = Vector2.One;

            // Add the ContainerVisuals to the visual tree
            ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(mainCanvas, _rootContainerVisual);
            _rootContainerVisual.Children.InsertAtTop(_containerVisualToRotate);
        }

        private void AddRectangleToContainer()
        {
            // Create a solid color brush
            var brush = _compositor.CreateColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightBlue);

            // Create a SpriteVisual to represent the rectangle
            var rectangleVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
            rectangleVisual.Size = new Vector2(300, 200); // Set size as per your requirement
            rectangleVisual.Brush = brush;

            // Add the rectangle to the container to rotate
            _containerVisualToRotate.Children.InsertAtTop(rectangleVisual);
        }

        private void RotateContainerVisual()
        {
            // Rotate the _containerVisualToRotate
            var rotationAnimation = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
            rotationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 360.0f, _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
            rotationAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            rotationAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

            _containerVisualToRotate.StartAnimation(nameof(Visual.RotationAngleInDegrees), rotationAnimation);
        }

        private void AdjustRootContainerSize()
        {
            // Adjust the size of _rootContainerVisual to accommodate the rotated content
            var size = new Vector2(400, 300); // Adjust as per your content size
            _rootContainerVisual.Size = size;
        }
    }


   

We create a Compositor instance and initialize the root and child ContainerVisuals.
A rectangle visual is added to the _containerVisualToRotate to represent the content you want to rotate.
We apply a rotation animation to the _containerVisualToRotate.
The _rootContainerVisual size is adjusted to accommodate the rotated content.
You need to ensure that you have the necessary references and namespaces imported for the Windows.UI.Composition namespace. Additionally, mainCanvas should be the name of the canvas in your XAML file where you want to display the composition visuals. Adjust the size and content of the visuals as per your application requirements.

Thanks for your answer!
Would you mind sharing the xaml file as well? I have trouble getting it right. Thanks!
